# JQuery logic isn't being applied to dynmically created html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've written the following JavaScript/JQuery code. This code is trigged when an option is selected from a HTML dropdown menu. It compares the value selected with values that have already been added to a HTML Table:

```
$('#addonSelectOptions').on('change', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var selectedAddon = $('#addonSelectOptions option:selected').val();
    var selectedText = $('#addonSelectOptions option:selected').text();
    var currentAddons = $('#acg_addons').val();

    if(selectedAddon == '0') {
        $('#availableAddOns > tbody:last').empty();
        $('#availableAddOns > tbody:last').append('<tr id="noaddonShown"><td>No add-ons</td></tr>');
        $('#acg_addons').val(' ');
    } else {

        var addonStrings = currentAddons.toString();
        var addonCheck = 'addOn-'+selectedAddon;

        $(".selectedAddonTableTR").each(function() {
            var rowID = $(this).attr('id');

            if(rowID == addonCheck) {
                alert('You have already added this Add On to this Game');
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#noaddonShown').empty();
                $('#availableAddOns > tbody:last').append('<tr id="addOn-'+selectedAddon+'" class="selectedAddonTableTR"><td>'+selectedText+'</td></tr>');
                var addons = $('#acg_addons').val();
                $('#acg_addons').val(addons+''+selectedAddon+',');
            }

        });

    }

});
```

If I select an option from the dropdown that already exists in the table, the alert is displayed (which it's meant to do). Then, if I select an option that isn't in the HTML table it will add it to the table (which is correct). However if I go to select the newly added option, the alert is triggered but it's then added a second time to the table. It's only supposed to display the alert, and not add it a second time.

What am I missing from the code to prevent this?

**EDIT:**
Based on missing an MCVE, here is the dropdown HTML:

```
<select id="addonSelectOptions">
    <option value="0">--No Addon--</option>
    <option value="2">Add On 1</option>
    <option value="1">Add On 2</option>
</select>
```

And this is the HTML Table that is used too:

```
<table id="availableAddOns">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="addOn-1" class="selectedAddonTableTR">
            <td>Add On 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're missing a MCVE.

Comment: I've added the missing dropdown and table HTML (thought I had included this).

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on the right path. You didn't do a good job explaining your problem, but I think this will get you in the right direction. Read my comments and let me know if you need more detailed explanations on what is happening.

```
$('#addonSelectOptions').on('change', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var select = $(this), //Don't use var declaration more than once
        selectedAddon = $(select).val(),
        selectedAddonIdString = 'addOn-' + selectedAddon,
        selectedText = $(select).find('option:selected').text(),
        availableAddOns = $('#availableAddOns'), // Cache your DOM elemtns, don't select them more than once
        currentAddonArr = []; //Use an array to store multiple values... I don't know what you were trying to do with addons = $('#acg_addons').val();

    if(selectedAddon == '0') {
        $(availableAddOns).find('> tbody:last').empty();
        //You didn't prove any HTML, but you can't dynamically add an HTML element here, but then reference it below since it may not exist
        //If this part of the if statement never fires, the #noaddonShown element will not exist
        $(availableAddOns).find('> tbody:last').append('<tr id="noaddonShown"><td>No add-ons</td></tr>');        // Rework this
    } else {

        if($.inArray(selectedAddonIdString, currentAddonArr) === -1) {
            //You don't need to run empty funtions on an element that will simply show the same information over and over again if a condition is met.
            //Instead use $('#noaddonShown').hide(); $('#noaddonShown').show(); to toggle the element
            $('#noaddonShown').empty(); // rework this
            $(availableAddOns).find('> tbody:last').append('<tr id="addOn-'+selectedAddon+'" class="selectedAddonTableTR"><td>'+selectedText+'</td></tr>');
            //var addons = $('#acg_addons').val(); not needed
            //$('#acg_addons').val(addons+''+selectedAddon+',');

        } else {
            alert('You have already added this Add On to this Game');
            return false;
        }

    }

});
```